# prestashop url to category

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

[PRESTASHOP 1.7] I want to display categories outside of ps_categorytree.

Here is the module code:

```
$allCategories = Category::getNestedCategories(null, $this->context->language->id);
$this->context->smarty->assign( 'allCategories' , $allCategories );

return $this->fetch('module:'.$this->name.'/views/templates/widget/block.tpl');
```

.tpl file:

```
{foreach from=$allCategories item=mainCategory}
   <a href="{$mainCategory.link}">{$mainCategory.name}</a>
{foreach from=$mainCategory.children item=subCategory}
   <a href="{$subCategory.link}">{$subCategory.name}</a>
{/foreach}
```

Error: Notice: Undefined index: link

How do I assign a link?

Comment: Take a look at the class Link in PrestaShop.

Answer (score 1):

Because of you got the Category as array, not an object.

Try to use mainCategory['link'] instead of mainCategory.link, and so on

**UPDATE**
I misunderstood the question, sorry!
Try this.

```
 {foreach $allCategories as $mainCategory}
    {$link->getCategoryLink($mainCategory.id_category, $mainCategory.link_rewrite)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
{/foreach}
```

If you have'nt $link variable in the smarty file, you should assign it

```
'link' => $this->context->link,
```

Comment: It's used as an array, that code is inside Smarty.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP, i have updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, I voted up!